# Access Django ManyToMany field values within Model.clean()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

It seems (though I'm having trouble finding it in the Django documentation) that `ManyToMany` fields are deferred when they are selected in the Django admin, and so effectively not set, during the call to a Django Model's [`.clean()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean).

Here's an example to illustrate.

**models.py**:

```
import uuid
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Country(models.Model):
    code = models.SlugField(max_length=2, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True, unique=True)

class Region(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True, unique=True)

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    regions = models.ManyToManyField(Region, blank=True)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, blank=True)
    field1 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    field2 = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=[("foo", "FOO"), ("bar", "BAR")]
    )

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(
            "Got id=%s, regions=%s, countries=%s, field1=%s, field2=%s"
            % (self.id, self.regions.all(), self.countries.all(), self.field1, self.field2)
        )
        if self.regions.exists() and self.countries.exists():
            raise ValidationError(_("'Regions' and 'Countries' are mutually exclusive"))
        super().clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

**admin.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from my_app.models import SampleModel
@admin.register(SampleModel)
class SampleModleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ("regions", "countries", "field1", "field2")
```

In Django shell after `./manage makemigrations && ./manage migrate`:

```
from my_app.models import Country, Region

Country.objects.bulk_create([
    Country(code="US", name="United States"),
    Country(code="UK", name="United Kingdom"),
])
Region.objects.bulk_create([
    Region(name="North America"),
    Region(name="EMEA"),
])
```

Above, `SampleModel` overrides `.clean()` **to enforce that `regions` and `countries` are mutually exclusive.**  (Specify one or the other, but not both.)

From the add page at `/admin/my_app/samplemodel/`:

[image]

From the runserver stdout I see (with newlines added):

```
Got
id=6340d6bf-3f38-45e6-b431-b56985240e45,
regions=<QuerySet []>,  # Why is this empty?
countries=<QuerySet []>,  # Same here
field1=100,
field2=bar
```

despite there being selected `regions` and `countries` in the model form.

**How can I properly access these values within `.clean()`?**

Comment: A many to many relationship is a set of entries in a linking table. It can't possibly be populated until the IDs for both sides of the relationship exist, which doesn't happen until the item is saved.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense @DanielRoseman - so, am I SOL here or can you think of some type of workaround?

Comment: I'm trying to get a better sense of the flow that occurs when a form with ManyToMany fields is submitted to be saved; I see what you're saying more clearly from reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/